# Generate dynamic column using server side code response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

This is my Server side code and its response

```
$response = array(
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "iTotalRecords" => $records,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecords,
    "aaData" => $data_arr,
    "dayFirstHeadingdynamic" => $monthallDates
);

return response()->json($response);

{
    "draw": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 11,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 11,
    "aaData": [
    {
    "Recruiter": "person name",
    "Day0": 0,
    "Day1": 0,
    "Day2": 0,
    "Day3": 0,
    "Day4": 0,
    "Day5": 0,
    "Day6": 0,
    "Day7": 0,
    "Day8": 0,
    "Day9": 0,
    "Day10": 0,
    "Day11": 0,
    "Day12": 0,
    "Day13": 0,
    "Day14": 0,
    "Day15": 0,
    "Day16": 0,
    "Day17": 0,
    "Day18": 0,
    "Day19": 0,
    "Day20": 0,
    "Day21": 0,
    "Day22": 0,
    "Day23": 0,
    "Day24": 0,
    "Day25": 0,
    "Day26": 0,
    "Day27": 0,
    "Day28": 0,
    "Day29": 0,
    "Day30": 0,
    "Total": 0
    }
    ],
    "dayFirstHeadingdynamic": [
        "2023-12-01",
        "2023-12-02",
        "2023-12-03",
        "2023-12-04",
        "2023-12-05",
        "2023-12-06",
        "2023-12-07",
        "2023-12-08",
        "2023-12-09",
        "2023-12-10",
        "2023-12-11",
        "2023-12-12",
        "2023-12-13",
        "2023-12-14",
        "2023-12-15",
        "2023-12-16",
        "2023-12-17",
        "2023-12-18",
        "2023-12-19",
        "2023-12-20",
        "2023-12-21",
        "2023-12-22",
        "2023-12-23",
        "2023-12-24",
        "2023-12-25",
        "2023-12-26",
        "2023-12-27",
        "2023-12-28",
        "2023-12-29",
        "2023-12-30",
        "2023-12-31"
    ]
}
```

I want to generate dynamic column by looping "dayFirstHeadingdynamic" => $monthallDates from server side code $response array, because dates in "dayFirstHeadingdynamic" response can be increase and decrease, below is my client side code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var month_year = "";
    var duration_date_from = "";
    var duration_date_to = "";
    var sortByRecruiterIncharge = [];
    var customSearch = "";
    
    rolesList = $('#day_qualifiedleads_report').DataTable({
        "deferRender": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering" : false,
        lengthMenu: [20, 50, 100, 200, 500],
        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo url('qualified-leads-reporting-dayWise-Filter');?>",
            data: function (data) {
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                    var status = $(this).val();
                    var title = $(this).closest('label').attr('title');

                    if(title === "sortByRecruiterIncharge"){
                        if(status === "All"){
                            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                                $('.btn-group.show input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                                $('.btn-group.show input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                                    sortByRecruiterIncharge.push($(this).val());
                                });
                            }else{
                                $('.btn-group.show input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
                                sortByRecruiterIncharge = [];
                            }
                        }else{
                            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                                sortByRecruiterIncharge.push(status);
                            }else{
                                sortByRecruiterIncharge = sortByRecruiterIncharge.filter(function (value) {
                                    return value !== status;
                                });
                            }
                            sortByRecruiterIncharge = removeDuplicatesFromArray(sortByRecruiterIncharge);
                        }
                    }
                });

                function removeDuplicatesFromArray(array){
                    return array.filter((value, index) => array.indexOf(value) === index);
                }
                
                data.month_yearoption = month_year;
                data.durationdatefrom = duration_date_from;
                data.durationdateto = duration_date_to;
                data.sortByRecruiterIncharge = sortByRecruiterIncharge;
                data.customSearch = customSearch;
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { data: 'Recruiter' },
            <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($monthallDates); $i++){?>
            { data: '<?php echo "Day$i";?>' },
            <?php } ?>
            { data: 'Total' }
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'multi'
        },
    });

    $('#month_year').change(function () {
        month_year = $(this).val();
        reloadTable('month_year',month_year)
    });

    $('#duration_date_from').change(function () {
        duration_date_from = $(this).val();
        reloadTable('duration_date_from',duration_date_from)
    });
    
    $('#duration_date_to').change(function () {
        duration_date_to = $(this).val();
        reloadTable('duration_date_to',duration_date_to)
    });

    $('#sortByRecruiterIncharge').change(function () {
        rolesList.draw();
        reloadTable('sortByRecruiterIncharge',sortByRecruiterIncharge)
    });

    $('#customSearch').keyup(function () {
        customSearch = $(this).val();
        reloadTable('customSearch',customSearch)
    });

    function reloadTable(field_name, value){
        var month_year = $("#month_year").val();

        var dateArray = month_year.split('-');
        var year = dateArray[0];
        var month = dateArray[1];

        var durationdateTo = $("#duration_date_to").val();
        var durationdateFrom = $("#duration_date_from").val();
        
        $('#day_qualifiedleads_report').DataTable().clear();
        $('#day_qualifiedleads_report').DataTable().destroy();
        
        $('#day_qualifiedleads_report').DataTable({
            "deferRender": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering" : false,
            lengthMenu: [20, 50, 100, 200, 500],
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": "_all" }
            ],
            ajax: {
                url: "<?php echo url('qualified-leads-reporting-dayWise-Filter');?>",
                data: function (data) {
                    data.month_yearoption = month_year;
                    data.durationdatefrom = duration_date_from;
                    data.durationdateto = duration_date_to;
                    data.sortByRecruiterIncharge = sortByRecruiterIncharge;
                    data.customSearch = customSearch;
                }
            },
            Instead of this columns code, I want to generate column dynamically as per response of server side code.
            "columns": [
                { data: 'Recruiter' },
                <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($monthallDates); $i++){?>
                { data: '<?php echo "Day$i";?>' },
                <?php } ?>
                { data: 'Total' }
            ],
            "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                if (month_year != null || durationdateTo!='' || durationdateFrom!='') {
                    $("#tablerowdaywise2").empty();
                    var dayFirstHeadingdynamic = json.dayFirstHeadingdynamic;
                                            
                    $("#tablerowdaywise2").append("<th>Recruiters</th>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < dayFirstHeadingdynamic.length; i++) {
                        $("#tablerowdaywise2").append("<th>" + dayFirstHeadingdynamic[i] + "</th>");
                    }
                    $("#tablerowdaywise2").append("<th>Total</th>");
                }
            },
            select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Since 3 days I am stuck up with this issue, In client side code I have tried so many solution to get desired result but unable, In function reloadTable(field_name, value) I have tried to change

```
"columns": [
    { data: 'Recruiter' },
    <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($monthallDates); $i++){?>
    { data: '<?php echo "Day$i";?>' },
    <?php } ?>
    { data: 'Total' }
],
```

to this, but unable to get desires result

```
"columns": (function (json) {
    var dynamicColumns = [];
    var columnsFromServer = json.dayFirstHeadingdynamic;
    for (var i = 0; i < columnsFromServer.length; i++) {
        dynamicColumns.push({ data: columnsFromServer[i] });
    }
    return dynamicColumns;
})(),
```

I have tried below code also, but still unable to get desired result.

```
"columns": function (settings, json) {
    var dayFirstHeadingdynamic = json.dayFirstHeadingdynamic;
    var dynamicColumns = [
        { data: 'Recruiter' },
    ];    
    for (var i = 0; i < dayFirstHeadingdynamic.length; i++) {
        dynamicColumns.push({ data: '<?php echo "Day$i";?>' });
    }  
    dynamicColumns.push({ data: 'Total' });
    return dynamicColumns;
},
```